Python - Stream file
I want to stream upload a file to a webserver. To achieve this I found this library: https://github.com/requests/toolbelt#multipartform-data-encoder
The code looks pretty straight forward:
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
import requests

m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={'field0': 'value', 'field1': 'value',
            'field2': ('filename', open('file.py', 'rb'), 'text/plain')}
    )

r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=m,
                  headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})

But how do I pass a stream to this MultipartEncoder instead of opening a file on disk? The reason is that I am fetching a file using stream=True as I don't want to save the file on disk. Like this:
def stream_file():
    url = "https://webserver.com/file.zip"
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as file_stream:
      print(file_stream.status_code)

My question is how do I pass this file_stream to the MultipartEncoder?

did you try to use file_stream in place of open('file.py', 'rb')?  Like 'field2': ('filename', file_stream, 'text/plain')} ? As I know file_stream is file-like object and open('file.py', 'rb') also creates file-like object

Yes I tried that - I get the error AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'encode'

you could add this in question with full error message

maybe if you change text/plain to something like application/zip then maybe it will send without encoding.

frankly, to test this problem it would need working server which sends zip as stream, code which gets it and tries to send to web server, and working web server which can get it.
